# Change function element IMG to DIV background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have static HTML structure and my background images are fullscreen every page. Added a img tag after  tag:

```
<img src="img/about.jpg" id="static_bg" alt="">
```

And CSS:

```
#static_bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: -2;}
.staticbgwidth { width: 100%; }
.staticbgheight { height: 100%; }
```

And final, my JS code:

```
$(window).load(function() {    

    var theWindow        = $(window),
    $bg              = $("#static_bg"),
    aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

    function resizeBg() {

        if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
            $bg
            .removeClass()
            .addClass('staticbgheight');
        } else {
            $bg
            .removeClass()
            .addClass('staticbgwidth');
        }

    }

    theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
```

Yeah, it's working good. But I want, remove my IMG and add a DIV background. When I change this, don't working JS.

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: what div background html u expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `background property in CSS` like,

```
#static_bg { background:url('img/about.jpg') ;
         position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: -2;}
```

And `Div` like,

```
<div id="static_bg"></div>
```

You can use `background-size:cover` and apply `background` on `body` if above not `works` see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DLVs9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="your_div"></div>

.your_div {
    background:url('img/about.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

set an ID to your image like this:

```
<img id="background-img" src="img/about.jpg" id="static_bg" alt="">
```

get your background url by this code:

```
var $bg-url = $("#background-img").attr("src");
```

then remove your image by css like this:

```
$("#background-img").css("display","none");
```

then set background for that element that you want. in this case `$("#static_bg")`

```
$("#static_bg").css("background-image",'url('"+$bg-url+'")');
```

[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/76XBB/)